# Webpack es2015 : browser can't find class

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6

### I have code `test.js`:

```
import * as engine from "./ctest"

var t = new engine()
t.init()
```

### The `src/ctest.js` is :

```
class engine {

    constructor() {
        console.log('test constructor test');
    }

    init() {
        console.log('popl');
    }
}

module.exports = engine;
```

### My `webpack.config.js` is :

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var root = path.resolve(__dirname);

module.exports = {
    entry: ["./src/test.js"],

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "test.js"
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

### My `.babelrc` is

```
{
    "presets": ["env"]
}
```

When i compile it with npm run watch and launch it in the browser i have a console error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: engine is not defined
at eval (test.js:9)
at Object../src/test.js (test.js:94)
at __webpack_require__ (test.js:20)
at eval (test.js:1)
at Object.0 (test.js:105)
at __webpack_require__ (test.js:20)
at test.js:69
at test.js:72"
```

which is `engine = new engine();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `babel-preset-env` & remove all other presets. Also note that you don't need to mention `presets` array in both `.babelrc` & `query` field inside `js` test. Mention it only once in `.babelrc` & remove the `query` field.

First do `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-env` & `npm remove babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-stage-2`

The complete structure looks like this.

## test.js

```
import engine from "./src/ctest";

const t = new engine();
t.init();
```

## src/ctest.js

```
class engine {
  constructor() {
    console.log("test constructor test");
  }

  init() {
    console.log("popl");
  }
}

module.exports = engine;
```

## .bablerc

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

## webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./test.js",

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "engine.js"
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /(node_modules)/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "Webpack-testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode development",
    "prod": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "node dist/engine.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.11"
  }
}
```

Now the first error is your entry point is wrong in **webpack.config.js**. Webpack needs the main file which includes all the other files. So in your case its **test.js** which includes **src/ctest.js** & not the other way round so it should be the entry point.

To run the application, try **npm run build** or **npm run prod** & then run **npm run start**. Note that I am using Webpack 4 that's why the flag **--mode** in **build** & **prod** scripts in **package.json**

Comment: I edited the question. And it's a bit better; now I have test.html:7 ` Uncaught TypeError: engine is not a constructor` in the `new egine()` line

Comment: why would you do it like that? put `var test= new engine();` code in the test file itself.

Comment: you didn't try my answer, did you? remove those presets you don't need them, you just need `babel-preset-env`

Comment: anyways I just updated my answer & its now working for your use case. ask me anything if you still have doubts but I think I have explained it well enough :)

Comment: Works perfectly. I have the feeling my learning will be painfull :)

Comment: upvote it plz & don't worry, just post it on here but put it nicely. your question didn't make sense at first so put whole question nicely. that way you will get fast answers. and if its Webpack you're struggling with join https://gitter.im/webpack/webpack

Comment: I already voted up for your post but someone voted down. :( sorry